# ClamAV not updating

Tags: clamav

How to update ClamAV

whenever i try to update clamAV i get the following report

"WARNING: Can't query current.cvd.clamav.net

WARNING: Invalid DNS reply. Falling back to HTTP mode.
Reading CVD header (main.cvd):

WARNING: can't read main.cvd header from db.local.clamnet.net"

[image]

i used freshclam once before and it worked fine but after a month when i tried i am getting this warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reconfiguring `freshclam` for updating from a different mirror.

At a terminal window type in:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure clamav-freshclam
```

Select OK

[image]

Select if you want `Freshclam` to run as a Daemon:

[image]

Select a mirror closest to you: (I'm in the US but there are mirrors all over the world)

[image]

HTTP Proxy can normally be left blank:

[image]

Type in how many times a day you want `Freshclam` to update:  (24 means once per hour)

[image]

Select if you want `clamd` to be notified after update:  (clamd is the scanner running all the time if you have it set up)

[image]

Select private mirror.  Should be blank.

[image]

Hope this helps!